# Using Where and Join together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have two tables, one storing the username and the other with their personal info. What I'm trying to get is a result where, I want to take the current active username and join it with the personal info table to get the ID, Username + their basic info to appear in a table. I came up with the query after googling, but it seems that I did something wrong. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

users = the table that contain username
userinfo table with their basic info
$username is basically a variable that was stored in the $SESSION

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT users.UserID, users.Username, userinfo.FirstName, userinfo.LastName,
FROM users
WHERE users.Username = $username
INNER JOIN userinfo
ON users.UserID=userinfo.UserID");
?>
```

Assuming I have the parse data to table coding right below that specific code, what is wrong with the query?
Basically the error I keep getting is error #1064 at line #2 (when I run the query without the php code). Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you're unsure about something related to syntax **DON'T GUESS**, check the documentation instead: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: I did not guess. I stumbled upon other stackoverflow answers and w3school and I adjusted them as I go. I know how to do it separately, I just cant seem to figure out how to do it together. I actually went through several documentations, just that its confusing for me. Sorry and thanks for helping.

Comment: "and I adjusted them as I go" --- that is guessing. Programming is not about adjusting something it's about following strong syntax rules defined in a documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT users.UserID, users.Username, userinfo.FirstName, userinfo.LastName
FROM users
INNER JOIN userinfo
ON users.UserID=userinfo.UserID
WHERE users.Username = $username
");
?>
```

Try this

Comment: Same error. I even try changing the variable to the data that exist in the db.

    WHERE users.Username = 'Test'

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT users.UserID, users.Username, userinfo.FirstName, userinfo.LastName,
FROM users
INNER JOIN userinfo
ON users.UserID=userinfo.UserID
WHERE users.Username = $username");
?>
```

The syntax is -

```
SELECT col, ...
FROM <tbl_name> AS t1
INNER JOIN <join_tbl_name> AS t2
ON t1.col = t2.col
WHERE <cond>
```

Comment: I actually tried the second answer you gave me by replacing all the tbl name and cond , still get the same error. But thanks anyway, you are very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

See the below code. If you print it, you will find where error occurs.

```
echo $query = mysql_query("SELECT users.UserID, users.Username, userinfo.FirstName, userinfo.LastName FROM users WHERE users.Username = '$username' INNER JOIN userinfo ON users.UserID=userinfo.UserID");
```

or use

```
$sql="SELECT users.UserID, users.Username, userinfo.FirstName, userinfo.LastName FROM users WHERE users.Username = '$username' INNER JOIN userinfo ON users.UserID=userinfo.UserID";
if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      echo "Unexpected Error <br/>";;
      die (mysql_error());
      }
```

where **$con** is mysql connection statement.

Comment: I have the connection in my header. I guess I screw up the query part badly thats why. But thanks really!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at the end of field select. Try removing that part:

```
$query = "SELECT users.UserID, users.Username, userinfo.FirstName, userinfo.LastName
FROM users
INNER JOIN userinfo
ON users.UserID=userinfo.UserID
WHERE users.Username = $username";
```